# How to determine whether a file has passed anti-virus detection?

Tags: malware, antivirus, virus, malware-detection, virus-scanning

We have to develop a Java web service that is running on WebLogic Server 12.2.1 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server. The web service allows clients to send files to it in BASE64 format, which the web service will then decode and then create actual files on the server with the decoded binary.

The server has Trend Micro OfficeScan Client installed, which I was told that it will scan for any file that is copied to the server. If the binary that I am writing to disk contains a virus, would the IO write fail immediately by the virus detection? I am not exactly sure when the virus scanning will take place. Is it immediately while a file is in the midst of being created on the server, or after a file has already been created on the server?

I need to know this because we want the web service to send an alert back to the client if the file that he sent contains a malware. Therefore how can the web service determine that no virus has been detected by Trend Micro OfficeScan Client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If "realtime protection" option is enabled in the AV, then it will immediately detect the virus "after" the writing operation is completed.
The best way I can think of for your scenario, is to programmatically invoke the AV to scan the file, using command line options of the AV. Then, you'll know for sure that the AV has finished the scanning and get the scanning results as well.